# How can I prevent my music apps from launching and playing on their own?

Tags: motorola-droid-x, bugs

When plugging headphones into my Droid X, I can listen to music for a little while. The issue will start if the headphones rotate while in place. This somehow triggers an event and my Droid X will start to play the default player, sometimes it will play Songbird...sometimes both. Sometimes when it does this it just keeps playing and pausing music. It seems really messed up on the hardware level. I intend to keep the device, as the only real issue is the default players launching.

My question is this: How can I prevent the default player(s) from launching and playing music ever?

Answer (score 2):

After doing some more research, I [found a thread](http://androidforums.com/droid-support-troubleshooting/53221-motorola-droid-music-player-starts-its-self.html) with a lot of users having the same exact problem:

Their solution is to use either [Headset Blocker](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.idunnolol.headsetblocker&hl=en) or [Disable Autoplay](http://www.appbrain.com/app/disable-autoplay/ix.com.android.DisableAutoPlay) apps. This seems to have sort of worked. Just make sure that taskkiller isn't disable either of these.

I am still experimenting on how to fix this issue...

**Edit1**: I still see the same issue even though both suggested apps are running. I believe the taskkiller app may be causing this issue. I am going to try disable it and seeing if this gets anywhere.

**Edit2**: Still no luck. I am going to try rooting my phone and installing [the Autostarts app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.elsdoerfer.android.autostarts)